# Which cell makes input row a corrupt row when reading csv file with Apache Spark

Tags: java, csv, apache-spark, schema

Having:

- a csv file with lots of columns.
- PERMISSIVE mode and column name for corrupt records set.

Is there any way to find out **which specific cell causes a row to be marked as corrupt**?
With default approach I can only see (in corrupt column) input row without any hint which cell was problematic within this row.
(I cannot use Databricks in case of any suggestions related to this platform)

Answer (score 1):

Only thing is to check columns in your DF for null value and concat to a single output field using foldLeft on all columns and aggregate the columns that are null to the single field.

BUT, if these fields can be null also, then that does not help.

You check the corrupt col as well in the record of course.

```
val badDf = someDF.filter($"_corrupt_record".isNotNull). ...apply foldLeft logic...
```

See https://www.sparkcodehub.com/spark/spark-dataframe-foldleft-foldright-guide for foldLeft examples.

Some inpiration, slightly different example:

```
val columns = Array("col1", "col2", "col3") 
val totalCol = columns.foldLeft(lit(0)) { 
     (total, colName) => total + col(colName) 
} 
val dfTotal = df.withColumn("total", totalCol)
```

This is as good as it gets, not 100% foolproof.